# Python cannot properly import from another folder

Tags: python, import, directory

I am trying to set up a python project from multiple directories to keep it clean. I have a parent folder **project**, and two sub-directories **project/sub1** and **project/sub2**.

In the **sub1** folder, there is a file named **Thing.py** that is shown below. All that is in there is a class to hold some variables. I have also tried no class, just globals in the file. Both result in the same issue.

In the **sub2** folder, there is a file that tries to import the `class Thing` from **Thing.py**. It seems importing is not an issue, but `Thing` has no attributes after it is imported, so I can't use anything from it.

I've tried looking up importing from other folders (with using the `sys` module, `sys.path.append(import path))`, and also things about **__init__.py** files, but I cannot get this to work.

Also, if I copy the file to the sub2 folder, it imports fine. The `print(dir())` function call prints some things, but nothing I made. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**project/sub1/Thing.py**

```
class Thing:
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

**project/sub2/Importing File**

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

sys.path.append(r"..\sub1")
import Thing
print(dir(Thing))
```

**print(dir()) output**

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Comment: You're adding a relative path (`..\sub1`) to your `sys.path`. Are you sure you're importing the right `Thing.py`? Try `print(Thing.__file__)` and double check the path is correct.

Comment: I am sure, yes. I even tried absolute paths and they are behaving the same way. I printed Thing.__file__ and got "..\Thing\__init__.py".

Answer (score 0):

I have added **init**.py to the project dir as well as to both the subdirectories. I am using a mac machine so my paths are different you can change them appropriately as you are using a windows machine (I guess).
I am running the importingfile.py file from **sub2** dir
[(screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Htt.png).

Comment: I have what you have, it didn't seem to change anything. However, somehow my problem went away. I was just messing around with names and files, ended up exactly where I started, and it somehow is working now. I have no clue why. The same folder structure, same names, same file make ups, but now it is picking up the class. Sorry for taking your guys' time.

However, if you have any clue why this happened in the first place, that would be good to know too. Pretty weird to me. And also, should I make an answer saying this then or what?